# Transfer records from db to another

Tags: database, visual-studio

in visual basic vs2019 i'm trying to copy records from an access mdb to another which is the same, however nothing happens when i run the code, no errors no advices but the data is not copied to the destination db. Could someone help me? Is there another way to do it? Thanks in advance.
Here is my code

```
TransferConnection(nfile) 'Open connection to second DB
    Dim con1 As OleDb.OleDbConnection = DBConnect.getDbConnection()
    Dim connTr As OleDb.OleDbConnection = DBConnect.getTEMPDbConnection

    Try

        'Create the data adapter with a SelectCommand using the first connection.
        Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT field1,field2 from TabName", con1)

        'InsertCommand with the connection temp.
        da.InsertCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO TabName  (field1,field2) VALUES (@cb, @frn)", connTr)

        ' insert parameters.
        da.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cb", "field1")
        da.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@frn", "field2")

        da.AcceptChangesDuringFill = False

        Dim dt As New DataTable

        'Get the data from the source database.
        da.Fill(dt)

        'Save the data to the destination database.
        da.Update(dt)


    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(Err.Description & "Errore nella procedura di archiviazione")
    Finally

    End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved with few lines of code. Maybe it can be helpful to someone:

```
Dim cmdTransf As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO [tabledest]  SELECT field1,field2 FROM [" & databasepath & "].[tablefrom]", cmdtransf)

    cmdtransf.ExecuteNonQuery()
    cmdtransf.Close()
```